# Weld edge vertices of BoxBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I am trying to create terrain in the shape of a cube which will allow for vertex displacement along the *y‑axis* of those on the top plane. All vertices adjacent to those of the top plane need to be connected.

In a performant manner, user input from either desktop or mobile would move them up or down.

---

From what I have read it is better to offload expensive operations to the GPU. I thought achieving the vertex displacement in a [`ShaderMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial) with a displacement `attribute` seemed like a perfect fit until I read the following:

> As of THREE r72, directly assigning attributes in a ShaderMaterial is no longer supported. A BufferGeometry instance (instead of a Geometry instance) must be used instead.

So it seems that using `attribute` for my `Geometry` is out of the question?

My attempt at displacing the vertices along the top plane using `BufferGeometry` in the `ShaderMaterial` however results in the following:

[image: BufferGeometry and Geometry displacement]

The top plane's vertices of the `BufferGeometry` are not connected to the other planes, contrary to those of the `Geometry`, which are connected by using its `mergeVertices` method. To my knowledge that method is not available for `BufferGeometry` objects?

Basically what started my fear, uncertainty and doubt concerning `Geometry` was [a post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4386) I read by mrdoob.

### Summary

I [already have this working](https://i.imgur.com/qhwQ03G.gifv) for `Geometry`, but would like to make use of the GPU with `ShaderMaterial`'s `attributes`, seemingly only supported by `BufferGeometry`, **if** it offers performance benefits for mobile and **if** `Geometry` might be deprecated in the future.

---

Here is a small snippet illustrating the issue:

```js
let winX = window.innerWidth;
let winY = window.innerHeight;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, winX / winY, 0.1, 100);
      camera.position.set(2, 1, 2);
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(winX, winY);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const terrainGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const terrainMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `
    attribute float displacement;
    varying vec3 dPosition;

    void main() {

      dPosition = position;
      dPosition.y += displacement;

      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(dPosition, 1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
  `
});
const terrainObj = new THREE.Mesh(terrainGeo, terrainMat);

let displacement = new Float32Array(terrainObj.geometry.attributes.position.count);
    displacement.forEach((elem, index) => {
      // Select vertex 8 - 11, the top of the cube
      if (index >= 8 && index <= 11) {
        displacement[index] = Math.random() * 0.1 + 0.25;
      }
});

terrainObj.geometry.addAttribute('displacement',
  new THREE.BufferAttribute(displacement, 1)
);

scene.add(camera);
scene.add(terrainObj);

const render = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();

const gui = new dat.GUI();

const updateBufferAttribute = () => {
  terrainObj.geometry.attributes.displacement.needsUpdate = true;  
};

gui.add(displacement, 8).min(0).max(2).step(0.05).onChange(updateBufferAttribute);
gui.add(displacement, 9).min(0).max(2).step(0.05).onChange(updateBufferAttribute);
gui.add(displacement, 10).min(0).max(2).step(0.05).onChange(updateBufferAttribute);
gui.add(displacement, 11).min(0).max(2).step(0.05).onChange(updateBufferAttribute);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r76/three.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">body { margin: 0 } canvas { display: block }</style>
```

Comment: A different approach to this problem is to use a skinned/rigged mesh and have the user control the bones instead.

Comment: @WacławJasper interesting approach. I haven't experimented with bones yet, but is it possible to interconnect all of them? I have trouble visualizing what the top plane would look like.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Just set the proper displacement for the vertices on the top edge of the side panels, too. (i.e., all vertices having y-coord > 0.49).

Comment: @WestLangley, I wondered, are there real advantages to using `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry` when the mesh is *actively* being deformed? I currently have [this](http://i.imgur.com/qhwQ03G.gifv) working with `Geometry` and it wasn't that hard to get right with the `merge()` method. `BufferGeometry`, however, proves to be quite challenging for me though. The documentation states that `BufferGeometry` *"reduces the cost of passing all this data to the GPU"*, but does it truly matter in this case? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use `Geometry`, a `BufferGeometry` is created by the renderer and passed to the GPU, anyway. Look at `mesh.geometry._bufferGeometry`. But the overhead in doing so is, I expect, minimal in your use case... I like your low-poly scene. : - )

Comment: @WestLangley Speedy response! Thank you, that means a lot! I'll see how this will go for now. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this question @Jason - I'm trying to do something similar. Did the edges of your Geometry get welded together when you called ```geometry.mergeVertices()``` - I'm still finding gaps in my geometry after I apply a displacement. Also, what was your strategy for identifying the top vertices? I'm performing my displacement in the shader and have found a crude way to identify the top vertices using normals - was curious what you went with. Cheers.

Comment: @Boris Apologies if my story is vague—quite some time has passed. I think I  converted my `BufferGeometry` to geometry using ` new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(obj)` and applied `mergeVertices`. It did most of what I needed, but I recall some issues due to points not being aligned on top of each other that well.

Identifying top vertices was easy due to their index and starting at 0. Based on the top plane's width and height I could grab the correct range of vertices. Feel free to ask more.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for the follow up @Jason - that really helps. Much appreciated!